# Why do equals() implementations always start from self checking even when it's redundant?

Tags: java, equals

I am learning to override Java's `equals()` method, and I can understand the correctness of many tutorials such as the following from https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode#handling-hash-collisions.

```java
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    // standard getters/setters/constructors
        
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
        
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id == user.id 
          && (name.equals(user.name) 
          && email.equals(user.email));
    }
    
    // getters and setters here
}
```

My Question is that the implementation starts from self-checking, like

```java
if (this == o) return true;
```

but this line seems to be redundant. If `o` references to the same object,
the last checking

```java
User user = (User) o;
return id == user.id 
  && (name.equals(user.name) 
  && email.equals(user.email));
```

will be true as well.

I have googled a lot, but cannot find any topic related to it.

Why does every implementation of `equals()` start with self-checking even when there is no need to do that?
Is this a performance issue or something?

Comment: It's just a trivially true case that can easily be checked. It's an optimization that has very little negative impact (it's a basic requirement for `equals` that each object compare equal to itself).

Comment: It is quickly testing to see if the object is the same before going through the task of checking each and every property (trivial in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first to call to `==` is an optimization. If `this` and `o` are the exact same object (i.e. `this == o` returns `true`), there's no need to perform the subsequent following operations of going over all the object's properties and comparing them one by one.